# Line is not showing in scipy probplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, visualization

[probplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NyXvj.png)

I am trying to draw a q-q plot using the scipy stats module. While displaying the graph, I am not getting a straight line in Age data distribution while a straight line is visible in the fare data distribution.
Why line is not showing in Age data distribution?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read SO [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a question. Please post code snippets and errors instead of links and images.

Answer (score 4):

I got the answer, it is due to the availability of missing values missing values in the dataset. after removing them i got the correct plot.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNcQW.png)